# why subtracting a negative is the same as adding a positive.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why subtracting a negative same as adding positive and adding a negative same as subtracting a positive why.i didn't get the logic why subtracting
2-(-3)=5. Pls give me a logical answer

Comment: Would you rather I remove a debt of three dollars or would you rather I just give you three dollars? You come out the same either way. If I give you 2 dollars and also remove a debt of 3 dollars, it’s the same as if I’d simply given you 5 dollars.

Answer (score 1):

There is some deep theory behind this, but here is the rundown:

- -3 is what is known as the 'additive inverse' of 3 (basically the opposite)
- Subtraction is just the inverse (opposite) of addition
- The inverse of an inverse of something is the original thing (think of a double negation, like "I am not not going to the park" = "I am going to the park")
- a-b is the same as a+(-b)
- So, 2-(-3)=2+(-(-3))=2+3=5

I hope this helps :D

Comment: Not sure what deep theory you’re referring to. We can give a common sense explanation (“removing a debt”) or we can give a short proof from the axioms. Either way, there’s nothing deep or scary.